# Django model relations how to make it optional

Tags: django, database-design

**models.py**:

```
class Time(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    who=  models.TextField(db_column='who')

class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    when=  models.ForeignKey(Time)
```

I need to record *Time* and *Task* but my problem is that there can be:

> 1) a Time without Task,
>
> 2) a Task without Time,
>
> 3) a Time with multiple Task

I've tried adding ForeignKey to Task as null and blank = True but django says that a "foreignKey can't be null"

Are there other way to make this "*optional*" relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when =  models.ForeignKey(Time, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

and make new migration to change the schema:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

you are getting

```
foreignKey can't be null
```

because your schema doesnot allow fk to be null

Answer (score 3):

You should do like this ::

It seems most likely that you added `null=True` after running `manage.py makemigrations`. You'll need to modify your database schema to allow null values in that column.